# grep Ipaddress in expect script

Tags: expect

I want to grep ipaddress from file and set it to variable in expect scritp

```
  send -- "cat $filename |grep ([0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\})\r"
  expect -re "([0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}) *$prompt$"
  set IP $expect_out(1,string)
```

but I'm not suceeding. Any idea? I'm using /usr/local/bin/expect. Thanks

Comment: Could you give us an example of the output you're trying to parse?

Comment: r@rn2osscs603> cd /var/opt/bla/edd/ARNE_SIU
ranosusr@rn2osscs603> grep -il FXL704 *
FXL704_FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE.xml
ranosusr@rn2osscs603>.................so this is the output, and in File: FXL704_FRTAMX_SIU_ARNE.xml I need to grep Ipaddress and aasign to variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick scan, it seems to me you're trying to match a double prompt in your statement. You seem to have a variable followed by a literal prompt at the end of your expect regexp. Are you sure that is what you want?

Aside from that, I strongly recommend that you put `expect_internal 1` somewhere at the top of your script, and that way expect will log output showing you what it is (and is not) matching. You really shouldn't be trying to debug regexp matching without it, it's like searching in the dark...

Comment: ok, I put the expect_internal 1 on the beginig of script. Any ideas how could I grep address from filename, and expect the address i expect -re command?

Comment: I believe your above approach is good. But I think you need to tweak your expect regexp so that it will match. Run the script with `exp_internal 1` set and you will see that expect will return a lot of useful information that will allow you to tweak your regexp. If you want, you can edit your question and add the debugging output, and we can help you interpret it... although you will see it is not hard to understand.

Comment: I bit new in this, so it didn't help me much. I mean it code is ok, but I don't know how grep ipaddress, I tried all version with number , but it's giving me errror. So basicly I need to grep general ipaddress and in next row, expect this address together with pattern already assigned.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output you get when you run your script *with* `expect_internal 1` in it (otherwise output is pretty sparse), in readable format, and I will try to be more specific.